# All Elements are Units or Nilpotent in a Ring with a Unique Prime Ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

I'm struggling on the basic verification that in a commutative ring with only one prime ideal $P$, all elements are units or nilpotent. I have all the facts in front of me: The nilradical is just $P$, which is also the Jacobson radical, and if $x \notin P$, then $P + (x) = (1)$--but I can't figure out how to put them together. How do I conclude that $x$ is a unit from this?

Comment: Every non-unit is in some maximal ideal.

Comment: Since every maximal ideal is prime, it's a *local ring*.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier Yep, that's exactly what I was missing, thanks!